# Need to invoke non-static method without object

Tags: c++, templates, object, static, circular-dependency

Consider the following piece of C++ code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int a;
};

class Bar {
public:
    int w = 1;
    bool are_foos_equal(Foo* f1, Foo* f2) { return f1->a * w == f2->a * w; }

    struct FooHash { size_t operator () (Foo* f) const { return f->a; } };
    struct FooEqual { 
        bool operator () (Foo* f1, Foo* f2) const { 
            return are_foos_equal(f1, f2); 
        } 
    };

    std::unordered_set<Foo*, FooHash, FooEqual> fooset;
};
```

Now, this doesn't compile because in the `operator ()` of `FooEqual` I cannot invoke non-static `are_foos_equal`.

My question is: is it possible for `fooset` to use `are_foos_equal` somehow? I know that I could just make `are_foos_equal` static but the example code I gave is just so that I could state my problem which, unfortunately, occured in a much bigger project, and even if that means that the design is somewhat wrong, I'd like to rescue it by some hacks, if possible.

**EDIT**

I added a non-static member variable `w` to `Bar` to emphasize "non-staticness" of `are_foos_equal`.

Comment: If you're open to **very** bad ideas, if the non-static method doesn't indeed access any non-static member, you could call it on a `nullptr` and pray. But why is it not static in the first place ?

Comment: You can also just create temporary Bar object and call `are_foos_equal` on it, it's allowed here.

Comment: What's to downvote here? The question is worded clearly, includes the relevant code etc.

Comment: What do you want to do about the object passed to the non-static method.  There seem to be two possibilities here:  It could be like your over simplified example and the method is non static for no good reason.  Or it could be that an object is really required.  In the second case you need to figure out what object you want used then create a binding so the combination of the object and method can be called as a static-like function.

Comment: Why is `are_foos_equal()` a member of `Bar` at all? It should be a member of `Foo`.

Comment: @EJP It shouldn't be a member at all.

Comment: @Quentin, EJP: I updated the question so that now the code, hopefully, makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Not to me. Whether two Foos are equal has nothing to do with Bar, either as a static or non-static member. You've created an imaginary problem here. @nwp Agreed, it should be a static friend of Foo at best. And really it should be an operator== function.

Comment: Multiplying both terms by Bar.w is merely pointless. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @EJP not that much imaginary problem. Think of `Bar` as a context, depending on which, some `Foos` are equal to one another and some are not. For example, let `Bar` represent the amount of alcohol in blood and `Foo` equality of shapes via the human perception. I hope it's not far-fetched. Also, I know that multiplying by `Bar.w` doesn't do anything really. But it wasn't my point to show the whole underlying logic of equality testing - I just stated a technical problem.

Comment: Consider using namespaces instead of classes to express which functions belong where.

Comment: In that case it is a mystery how you can invoke a method that requires a comparison context without having a comparison context: in other words, why the operator() is static. Either the context is required or it isn't. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: There are various way to code around it, but you haven't provided a plausible motivation for the problem yet.

Comment: @EJP what about the alcohol and vision scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain a reference to the parent `Bar` object in `FooEqual`:

```
Bar() : fooset{10, FooHash{}, FooEqual{*this}}
{}

struct FooEqual {
    Bar& parent;
    bool operator () (Foo* f1, Foo* f2) const { 
        return parent.are_foos_equal(f1, f2); 
    } 
};
```

Because of how the constructors are declared in `std::unordered_set` you need to provide a bucket count, which is a bit unfortunate. You could get the default from a default-constructed `std::unordered_set` if you felt like it.

Comment: Nice, haven't somehow thought about that one.

Comment: Providing bucket count doesn't bother me much. That's the solution I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Move `are_foos_equal()` outside of the class and make it a free function.  It doesn't make sense that it should be a member of `Bar`.  Example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int a;
};

bool are_foos_equal(Foo* f1, Foo* f2)
{return f1->a == f2->a;}

class Bar {
public:
    struct FooHash { size_t operator () (Foo* f) const { return f->a; } };
    struct FooEqual {
        bool operator () (Foo* f1, Foo* f2) const {
            return are_foos_equal(f1, f2);
        }
    };
    std::unordered_set<Foo*, FooHash, FooEqual> fooset;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct option would definitely be to make `are_foos_equal` static. I would strongly suggest doing this instead of a hack. The larger the project, the cleaner it needs to be so that it doesn't devolve into an unmaintainable mess.

But if that is seriously not an option, I see a few other possibilities:

- Create a `Bar` object on the fly inside `FooEqual`:

  ```
  return Bar().are_foos_equal(f1, f2);
  ```
- Have `FooEqual` store a static `Bar` object for this purpose:

  ```
  bool operator() (Foo* f1, Foo* f2) const {
    static Bar bar;
    return bar.are_foos_equal(f1, f2);
  }
  ```
- Invoke *Undefined Behaviour,* invoke `are_foos_equal` on a null pointer and hope that it doesn't do anything bad. I **strongly discourage** this:

  ```
  return static_cast<Bar*>(nullptr)->are_foos_equal(f1, f2);
  ```

Comment: I deny any responsibility about the third option.

Comment: @Quentin Don't worry, it wasn't inspired by your comment, I thought of it as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here it could be trivial, because `are_foos_equal` could be static, as it neither use not change anything in `this`

=> first way just declare `are_foos_equal` static.

Alternatively, if the called function cannot be static because it uses or changes it object, you will have to change `FooEqual` to contain a `Bar` object (or a pointer or reference to it) . Because C++ is not java: inner classes have no hidden pointer to an object of enclosing class.

=> second way add a reference to a `Bar` in `FooEqual` and set it at construction time:

```
struct FooEqual {
    const Bar &bar;
    FooEqual(const Bar& bar): bar(bar) {};
    bool operator () (Foo* f1, Foo* f2) const { 
        return bar.are_foos_equal(f1, f2); 
    }
```